# Empty file uploaded to ftp server

Tags: java, apache, ftp

I am using apache's FTP client to upload file to the ftp server. But the issue is there is no exception thrown from the code but the file uploaded is empty. What could be the reason for this.
I am uploading same file twice but with different name as below.

```
    ftpClient.storeFile(fileDir+"//"+"actualFileName", inputStream));
    ftpClient.storeFile(fileDir+"//"+"differentFileName", inputStream));
```

Comment: You are not uploading a binary file in text mode, are you?

Comment: I have the InputStream available of the file to be uploaded and I have set the file type as binary file for FTPClient

Comment: Post the code you wrote for uploading the file, it may help others to identify if there is any error in the logic.

Comment: Do you reopen/recreate/reset the input stream before writing to second file from it?

Comment: No. AND Reset is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's the second file that ends up empty. You should recreate the inputStream for the second update (per DRCB's comment), otherwise it will be empty (it'll have got used up by the first upload).

Comment: Is there some wat to preserve the inputstream as it would not be possible to recreate.

Comment: You can copy the InputStream into a byte array (use commons-io to do this in one line) and use a `ByteArrayInputStream` as the source for storeFile.

Answer (score 0):

A remark: "//" seems a bit strange, should not it be "/"?

You repeat storeFile with the same inputStream, which will have been read to the end. InputStream has a read position. Consequently the second file certainly is empty. Also do not forget to `close()` the input stream to not lose file handles.